# Round ST_Distance

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am looking for a possibillity to round the result of `ST_Distance` on two digits.
If I try

```
select g.id ,round(ST_Distance(g.geom, p.geom), 2) dist_m
```

I get:

> Funktion round(double precision, integer) existiert nicht
>
> *function round(double precision, integer) does not exist*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first place to look is always the PostgreSQL docs (i.e. [Mathematical Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE))!

When using the two parameter signature of `ROUND()`, the function expects a `NUMERIC` type as its first input; you can simply cast the value (`::`):

```
SELECT g.id,
       ROUND(ST_Distance(g.geom, p.geom)::NUMERIC, 2) AS dist_m
FROM   ...
;
```

Comment: Naturally, the second step would be to check the return type of [`ST_DIstance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html); it's `FLOAT`, which is SQL standard for `DOUBLE PRECISION`