# Rounding decimal numbers in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinates, xy, round-function

I have a *'cities'* point layer. I want to compute a table with the coordinates of the geometries which works fine with that expression:

```sql
select
    name,
    ST_X(geom) as x_coordinate,
    ST_Y(geom) as y_coordinate
from
    cities
```

Now I want to round the values because there are many digits after the comma. I only want to have 2 digits after the comma. Why does the following expression doesn't work for me?

```sql
select
    name,
    round(ST_X(geom),2) as x_coordinate,
    round(ST_Y(geom),2) as y_coordinate
from
    cities
```

The error message I get is:

> ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via [Round ST_Distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342271/round-st-distance) you need to cast the values to a numeric:

```sql
select
  name,
  round(ST_X(geom)::numeric, 2) as x_coordinate,
  round(ST_Y(geom)::numeric, 2) as y_coordinate
from cities
```

You could also use [`ST_ReducePrecision`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ReducePrecision.html) but I am not sure how that handles the funny bits about floating-point value representation.